White smoke from my car Toyota 04
My car, Toyota 04 is bringing out white smoke from the exhaust and I tried servings it, change the plugs also

White smoke usually indicates a coolant leak into the engine (not good).

Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! What @JonCuster stated.
